# На чем реализована "Карта Трансформации" на сайте Всемирного Экономического Форума?

Tags: веб-программирование, framework, graph, neo4j

Может кто-нибудь знает или сможет определить, на чем (язык, фреймворк, приложение) реализована карта на сайте Всемирного Экономического Форума?

[Transformation Map](https://intelligence.weforum.org/topics/a1G0X000006NvAbUAK/)

Бэкэнд, насколько я могу судить сделан на основе neo4j, но вот никак не могу разобраться или найти в сети, как сделана визуализация карты на сайте.

[Об использовании neo4j](https://neo4j.com/blog/building-a-global-issues-graph-for-world-leaders/)

Comment: яваскриптом пересобирают svg картинку

Comment: что касается самого сайта он на реакте, вас интересует компонет круговой?

Comment: что касается компонента `TransformationMap` то он принадлежит этой компании https://www.serendipityai.co.uk правда для того чтобы его использовать нужно связаться с компанией

Comment: @eri спасибо за идею. С svg не знаком, буду разбираться.

Comment: @DaniilLoban
Спасибо за наводки.
Даниил, а можно узнать источник информации про принадлежность кругового компонента компании https://www.serendipityai.co.uk/ , если не секрет?

Comment: @ch9ch9n, если очень интересно то вот мое [расследование](https://youtu.be/ASXJ3X063oQ)